# Osx: Core Audio: Parse raw, compressed audio data with AudioToolbox (to get PCM)

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I am downloading various sound files with my own c++ http client (i.e. mp3's, aiff's etc.). Now I want to parse them using Core Audio's *AudioToolbox*, to get linear PCM data for playback with i.e. OpenAL. According to this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks.html , it should be possible to also create an audio file from memory. Unfortunately I didn't find any way of doing this when browsing the API, so what is the common way to do this? Please don't say that I should save the file to my hard drive first.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using an input memory buffer, avoiding any files, in my case I started with AAC audio format and used apple's api :  AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer  to do the hardware decompress into LPCM.  The trick is you have to define a callback function to supply each packet of input data.  That api call does the format conversion on a per packet basis.  In my case I had to write code to parse the compressed AAC data to identify packet starts (0xfff) then use the callback to spoon feed each packet into the api call.  I am also using OpenAL for audio rendering which has its own challenges to avoid using input files.